# Handle returned by GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) becomes invalid on second call to WriteFile

Tags: assembly, winapi

I am getting handle to stdout with `GetStdHandle` and first time it prints the message without any problem. But if I try to use the same handle second time, `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.section .data
msg:  .ascii "Hello, World"
msg1: .ascii "Hello, World\n"

.section .text
.global _start

_start:
    call    _main
    mov     rcx, 0
    call    ExitProcess
    
_main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32

    mov     rcx, -11
    call    GetStdHandle
    mov     rbx, rax

    mov     rcx, rbx
    lea     rdx, [rip + msg1]
    mov     r8, 13
    lea     r9, [rbp - 4]
    push    0
    call    WriteFile

    call    GetLastError
 
    mov     rcx, rbx
    lea     rdx, [rip + msg]
    mov     r8, 12
    lea     r9, [rbp - 4]
    push    0
    call    WriteFile

    call    GetLastError

    mov     rsp, rbp
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

Comment: `lea     r9, [rbp - 4]` - isn't that inside the shadow space you're reserving?  Or no, it's inside the space from the `push 0` which misaligns the stack.  You might have got Writefile to overwrite one of its incoming args.  IDK why it would be different on first vs. second call, but try fixing it by passing a pointer to space that you own.

Comment: One difference is that the 1st call is made with the stack not aligned by 16 because you make an even number of 8-byte pushes and `sub rsp` a multiple of 16.  Assuming that RSP on entry to `_start` was aligned by 16; that would be true for a Linux `_start` process entry point which isn't a real function (no caller and no return address), but IDK about Windows.  If your `_start` gets called by something in user-space, or otherwise starts with `RSP % 16 == 8`, then the stack alignment behaviour for `main` is opposite a normal function, and the first `WriteFile` would have RSP aligned.

Comment: The `push 0` is writing in the wrong place as well since that is supposed to be the 5th argument on top of the shadow space.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am newbie in assembly and just follow some tutorials. Could you please suggest what exactly can I do to try fix it?

Comment: One approach to debugging: get a minimal reproduction working in C and then follow what the compiler does.

Comment: Look for better tutorials if the ones you were looking at didn't explain what shadow space or stack alignment is.  Or search for those terms, e.g. `site:stackoverflow.com assembly shadow space`.  Also Jester's right, `push` comes after `sub rsp, 0` so it's not a 5th arg, it's making higher up memory into a 5th arg.  So the 2nd call has the 5th arg overlapping the space the first call used for `lea r9, [rbp - 4]`

Comment: @PeterCordes moving `push 0` before `sub rsp` fixed the issue. I start to understand now, thank you